# how to create order programmatically logged in customer?

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently I make php script to generate order not logged in customer but i want to use this script for logged in customer dynamically for logged in customer my code is

thanks

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')

->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());


// for guest orders only:
$quote->setCustomerEmail('customer@email.com');
//}
// add product(s)
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1307,1305);
$buyInfo = array(
'qty' => 1,
// custom option id => value id
// or
// configurable attribute id => value id
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));
//$quote->addProduct($product2, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));
$addressData = array(
'firstname' => 'Test',
'lastname' => 'Test',
'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
'city' => 'Somewhere',
'postcode' => '123456',
'telephone' => '123456',
'country_id' => 'US',
'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
);
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
echo "quote save";
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
echo "order save";
$order = $service->getOrder();
printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
}catch(Exception $e){

    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

this script is create order programaticaly for not loggedin customer

Comment: Is this the script exactly as you use it because it's not actually valid at the moment?  For instance, there is a `try catch` without the opening `try`, and loading of the product is wrong - you can't pass 2 ids, only an id and a column to `load()`

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your file

```
// for login customer orders only:
$email = "customer@email.com";

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);

$quote->setCustomer($customer)
    ->setCheckoutMethod($customer->getMode())
    ->setPasswordHash($customer->encryptPassword($customer->getPassword()));
```